# Python calculate ORFs from any arbitrary reading frame

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a big fasta file in this format:

```
>gi|142022655|gb|EQ086233.1|522 marine metagenome JCVI_SCAF_1096627390048 genomic scaffold, whole genome shotgun sequence
AAGACGGGCACCGTGTCCTTCGCGACGTACTCCGACCAGTTGTACACGTTCAGGTTGGTGTCGCCGGCAT
GGGCCGACAGGCTGGCCGCGACGGCCAGCGCCGCCGACGTGACGCGCGCGGCGCGCAACGCCGATTGACG
ACGGATACGGATACGCATGGGGATTCTCCTTGTGATGGGGATCGGCCGTTGCGCCCGGTCCGGGTCCGGA
CTCGCGTCAACGCCGTCGAGCGGTGTTCAGCACAAGGGCCAATGTAGAGATCGCGGCCGGCAGCGTCAGT
CCCGAAAACCGGGACAAACGGCGACGTCGATTCCCGCCGTTTGGGTAGATTCCCGCGTAGGCAGTCGAAA
ATATTCGTGATACCTGTAGCGCCACCTGAAAATCTTCGATACACGACGCCATGAGCGCTGCGCTGCCCGC
CCCCGATCTTCCGCTGAGCCACGTCGCGTTCGTGACTGAAACGCTGGGCGACATCGCACAAGCCGTCGGA
ACGCCGCAGTTCATGCGCGCCGTCTACGACACGCTCGTGCGCTACGTCGATTTCGACGCCGTGCACCTCG
ACTACGAGCGCAGCGCGTCTTCCGGCCGGCGCAGCGTCGGCTGGATCGGCAGCTTCGGCCGCGAGCCCGA
GCTGGTCGCGCAGGTGATGCGCCACTACTACCGCAGCTACGCGAGCGACGATGCAACTTACGCGGCGATC
GAAACCGAAAACGACGTGCAATTGCTGCAGGTGTCCGCGCAACGCGTGTCGAGCGAGCTACGGCATCTGT
TCTTCGATGCCGGCGACATTCATGACGAATGCGTGATCGCCGGCGTGACGGGCGGCACGCGCTACTCGAT
CTCGATCGCGCGCTCACGGCGGCTGCCGCCGTTTTCGCTGAAGGAACTGAGCCTGCTGAAGCAGCTTTCG
CAAGTCGTGCTGCCGCTGGCGTCCGCGCACAAGCGCCTGCTCGGCGCGATCTCCGCCGACGACGCACCGC
GCGACGAACTCGATCTCGACCTCGTCGCGCAATGGCTGCCGGAATGGCAGGAACGGTTGACCGCGCGCGA
GATGCATGTGTGTGCGTCGTTCATCCAGGGCATGACGTCGGCGGCCATCGCCCAATCGATGGGGCTCAAG
ACCTCCACCGTCGATACCTACGCGAAGCGCGCCTTCGCGAAGCTCGGCGTCGATTCGCGAAGGCAACTGA
TGACCCTCGTGCTGAGAAACGCGTCGCGGCGGCATGACGCATAGCATCC
>gi|142022655|gb|EQ086233.1|598 marine metagenome JCVI_SCAF_1096627390048 genomic scaffold, whole genome shotgun sequence
TTGCCGCCGGCCGCAGCCGGCTTGGCACCACGCTGCGGCTGGTCGCCGGACTTCGGCTTCGCGCCGGTGT
CCGCCGGCGCTGCCGGCCGCTTCGCGTTGCGCTCCTGCTTGGCCTTCGCTGCGAGCTGCGCCCGCAATTC
GGCAAGTTGTTCAAAACCCATAAATTCAATCCACCAGGAATATAAGGTGTGGTTCGTGCGGCCATGCCGC
GCGGCGCACGAGCTTCGCCGCCATGCGTGCGACCCGTCTGCCGCCGATGCGGAATACTACGGGGCCGCAT
>gi|142022655|gb|EQ086233.1|143 marine metagenome JCVI_SCAF_1096627390048 genomic scaffold, whole genome shotgun sequence
CTGATGCGTGCGCGCGGCCGCCTGCAGCCAGCGCGTCAGTTCCGGCGCCGCCGCGCGGCTGTAGTTCAGCGCG
CCGCCGCGATCGACGGGCAGGTAATGGCCTTCGATGTCGATGCCGTCCGGCGGCGTGTTCGAGTTCGCGA
TCGAGCCGAACTTGCCGGTCTTGCGCGCCTCGACGTACGTGCCGTCGTCGACGTACTGGATCTTCAGGTC
GACGCCGAGCCGCTGCCGCGCCTGCGCCTGCAGCGCCTGCAGCAGCACGTCGCGCTGGTCGCGCACGGTC
```

I want to be able to find out the length of the longest open reading frame (ORF) appearing in reading frame 3 of any of the sequences?

So far, I have tried some code that lists out all the ORFs of one sequence, inputted as a string:

```
import re
from string import maketrans

pattern = re.compile(r'(?=(ATG(?:...)*?)(?=TAG|TGA|TAA))')

def revcomp(dna_seq):
    return dna_seq[::-1].translate(maketrans("ATGC","TACG"))

def orfs(dna):
    return set(pattern.findall(dna) + pattern.findall(revcomp(dna)))

print orfs(Seq)
```

where `Seq='''CTGATGCGTGCGCGCGGCCGCCTGCAGCCAGCGCGTCAGTTCCGGCGCCGCCGCGCGGCTGTAGTTCAGCGCGCCGCCGCGATCGACGGGCAGGTAATGGCCTTCGATGTCGATGCCGTCCGGCGGCGTGTTCGAGTTCGCGATCGAGCCGAACTTGCCGGTCTTGCGCGCCTCGACGTACGTGCCGTCGTCGACGTACTGGATCTTCAGGTCGACGCCGAGCCGCTGCCGCGCCTGCGCCTGCAGCGCCTGCAGCAGCACGTCGCGCTGGTCGCGCACGGTC'''`  Notice that this is the 3rd entry in the big fasta file format above.

My sample output to this is: `set([])`, so I am clearly doing something terribly wrong.  My code doesn't even scale to multiple entries (i.e., it only takes a single DNA string, called `Seq`)

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

**EDIT**:

N.B.: `ATG` is the start codon (i.e., the beginning of an ORF) and `TAG`, `TGA`, and `TAA` are stop codons (i.e., the end of an ORF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED 1:  Completely rewritten to better match problem description.

I don't know the exact file format here, so am assuming it carries on the same way as the three sequences you show -- one sequence after another.

If I understand correctly, the reason you didn't see a match in the third sequence is that there actually isn't a match there.  There are matches in the first two, though, and you will see them if you run this.

'''

```
import re
import string

with open('dna.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

data = [x.split('\n', 1) for x in data.split('>')]
data = [(x[0], ''.join(x[1].split())) for x in data if len(x) == 2]

start, end = [re.compile(x) for x in 'ATG TAG|TGA|TAA'.split()]

revtrans = string.maketrans("ATGC","TACG")

def get_longest(starts, ends):
    ''' Simple brute-force for now.  Optimize later...
        Given a list of start locations and a list
        of end locations, return the longest valid
        string.  Returns tuple (length, start position)

        Assume starts and ends are sorted correctly
        from beginning to end of string.
    '''
    results = {}
    # Use smallest end that is bigger than each start
    ends.reverse()
    for start in starts:
        for end in ends:
            if end > start and (end - start) % 3 == 0:
                results[start] = end + 3
    results = [(end - start, start) for
               start, end in results.iteritems()]
    return max(results) if results else (0, 0)

def get_orfs(dna):
    ''' Returns length, header, forward/reverse indication,
        and longest match (corrected if reversed)
    '''
    header, seqf = dna
    seqr = seqf[::-1].translate(revtrans)
    def readgroup(seq, group):
        return list(x.start() for x in group.finditer(seq))
    f = get_longest(readgroup(seqf, start), readgroup(seqf, end))
    r = get_longest(readgroup(seqr, start), readgroup(seqr, end))
    (length, index), s, direction = max((f, seqf, 'forward'), (r, seqr, 'reverse'))
    return length, header, direction, s[index:index + length]

# Process entire file
all_orfs = [get_orfs(x) for x in data]

# Put in groups of 3
all_orfs = zip(all_orfs[::3], all_orfs[1::3], all_orfs[2::3])

# Process each group of 3
for x in all_orfs:
    x = max(x)   # Only pring longest in each group
    print(x)
    print('')
```

Comment: Nice effort, but I'm not sure that this analyzes the whole file (i.e., how does the output specify where that ORF came from)?

Comment: Actually I just noticed 3 issues:  (1) it doesn't do the whole file, but that's easy to rectify, I think.  (2) that's not a valid ORF, and the reason your code didn't find it is because 61 is not a factor of 3, and (3) Both our codes have the issue that findall finds all _non-overlapping_ sequences, so it need a bit more effort.  Let me update my answer to look at these things.

Comment: Ok, see what you can do.  It's a great start.

Comment: I've finally distilled it down to something a lot more manageable: I'm looking for a way to examine each reading frame (all three combined) and tell me for each one: reading frame 1 has a longest ORF consisting of XXX, reading frame 2 has a longest ORF consisting of YYY, reading frame 3 has a longest ORF consisting of ZZZ.  I.e., I want it to print out the length of the longest ORF **of each** reading frame, along with the associated ORF itself (i.e., the substring of bases).  Sorry it wasn't clear the first time I explained it.  Can you plz rewrite your code one more time? +1 for your effort

Comment: Still not completely clear, but the code now shows only the longest one out of each group of 3...

Comment: That's the thing... it shouldn't be showing the longest. As the title of the question implies: it should calculate the length of all ORFs from all three reading frames (i.e., I'm not interested in the longest).  Please edit your code to meet these requirements.  ... I'm only interested in the comprehensive calculation of each ORF from any arbitrary reading frame. They are ALL important to me. I hope that makes sense, sorry for being unclear. Let me know if that makes sense.  I've +1'ed you as well to convey my appreciation for your efforts.  Thanks again.

Comment: This seems contradictory.  In your question you say "I want to be able to find out the length of the longest open reading frame (ORF) appearing in reading frame 3 of any of the sequences?"  Here, you say "I'm only interested in the comprehensive calculation of each ORF from any arbitrary reading frame. They are ALL important to me."

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements aren't clear to me.  In your question you say "*I want to be able to find out the length of the longest open reading frame (ORF) appearing in reading frame 3 of any of the sequences?*" In subsequent comments, you say "*I'm only interested in the comprehensive calculation of each ORF from any arbitrary reading frame. They are ALL important to me.*"

Assuming that the later is what you're after, here's a simple way to get all the ORFs from a collection of sequences in fasta format, using BioPython to look after much of the work.

```
import io    # Only needed because input is in string form 
from Bio import Seq, SeqIO
import regex as re

startP = re.compile('ATG')

def get_orfs(nuc):
    orfs = []
    for m in startP.finditer(nuc, overlapped=True):
        pro = Seq.Seq(nuc)[m.start():].translate(to_stop=True)
        orfs.append(nuc[m.start():m.start()+len(pro)*3+3])
    return orfs

for fasta in SeqIO.parse(io.StringIO(fasta_inputs), 'fasta'):
    header = fasta.description
    orfs = get_orfs(str(fasta.seq))
    print(header, orfs)
```

Notes:

1. Normally you'd read a fasta collection from a file.  Since here it's in string format, we used io.StringIO to make it easily compatible with `SeqIO.parse` from BioPython
2. The `get_orfs` function finds ATGs and returns the ORG originating from each one.  If you're also interested in frames 4 through 6, you'll need the [`reverse_complement`](http://biopython.org/wiki/Seq#Complement_and_reverse_complement) of the sequence.
3. If you're only interested in the longest ORF from each fasta sequence, you could have the get_orfs function `return (max(orfs, key=len))`
4. It's marginally more difficult if you're only interested in ORFs starting with ATG in a specific frame (e.g. frame 3).  The simplest approach there might be to simply find all ORFs from the frame and then discard those not starting with ATG.